# Stack overflow with merge sort algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-efficient

I'm trying to order a file with 577000 lines by year. 
I'm putting the information of which line in a doubly linked list.
To order the file I tried to implement the merge sort algorithm , but because the algorithm is recursive when ordering a large quantity of information the algorithm doesn´t work because of the overflow of the stack memory.
Can someone help try to find a more efficient algorithm that doesn´t crash and doesn´t take too long ?

From a comment:

The dates ranger from 1730 to 2013

Comment: Use loops instead of recursion? Recursion is just a fancy kind of loop anyway, but one that is prone to faults like stack overflow.

Comment: A correctly written merge sort cannot cause stack overflow with a data size **as small as** N = 577000! it would recurse only max ~**20 times**.

Comment: I recommend using the _QuickSort_ sorting algorithm (for C language, you'll find a lot of ready-made example codes on the Internet). Forget about what system or platform you are using. Linux ? Windows ? MS-DOS :) ? And what version of the system ? Which C-language do you mean: C / C++ / C# ? You write about 577k rows, but what type are the data ? Do you want to sort string data or numeric data (integer, float, ...) ? Why did not you create your source code at the same time ?

Comment: I'm using c language just c. Using linux ubuntu 16-04. I'm saving in which node a structure of data. The problem of sorting at the same time that I'm saving is that is takes too long to store the data and order it.

Comment: So each line contains a year. Like: "1978 some text", right? And you need to sort it by year only? What are the range of years? 1900 to 2100 or ... ? To give a good answer we'll need such information. With the information I have, it seems that you should organize data as you read it.

Comment: The dates ranger from 1730 to 2013. But the problem is that using a algorithm like insertion sort takes more than half and hour to run..

Comment: Must the sort be conservative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a complex sorting. Given that you only need to cover about 300 different years this is what I would do.

Make an `array[300]` of linked list. Index zero is the linked list for the year 1730. Index 1 is the linked list for year 1731.

Now when you read a new entry from the file, you can find the array index by subtracting 1730 from the year read. Then you add the element to the linked list at that index.

When the whole file has been read, you put all the linked list together to a single linked list starting from index 0.

Now you have a linked list sorted by year.